# How to .setValue of a cell in spreadsheets being copied/named in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I (with help) created a script that creates folders, copies a file 15 times, renames the file, and puts the new renamed files into the folders it created.

I am trying to edit the script so it uses .setValue to edit the new file it has copied, setting the "I9" cell of the new copied files to:

.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Question Details!C' + j + 3 + ':AX' + j + 3 + ')');

I don't know how to edit the newly created spreadsheets as its looping through and creating them.  I'm not sure how to edit a sheet that is an "object" in the script.  When I would run the script, it would say it couldn't get copySheet.getRange(1,9,1,1); of an object.

Now, I was trying to use "J" from the for loop in the new formula added to this cell so I can get it to increase dynamically according to the value of "J" and I can't get it to work.  (This for loop is used to increase the number in the name of the sheet already) I'm sure that my syntax is way off.  But, forgive me.  I am still learning and really enjoy learning from the help on SO.

I also wondered if it made more sense to set it to loop through the these new folders/files afterwards and edit the "I9" cell in each?  Not sure...

SCRIPT BELOW
The code that I tried to add in script is notated at the bottom of the script.  I'm sure it's way off base, but I'm trying.  Any help you guys could give me would be much appreciated!
Thanks!
Brandon

```js
  var folderIds = [];

function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Data System Tool')
       .addItem('Create Data System Folders', 'copyAndRenameTemplate')
       .addToUi();
}

function copyAndRenameTemplate() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangeOfFileNames = ss.getRange("B4:B");
  var twoD_Array = rangeOfFileNames.getValues();
  var arrayOfFileNames = twoD_Array.join().split(",");
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();

  Logger.log(folderType);
  Logger.log(cell);
  
//  throw new Error('Script Halted! Check out the logs!!');
  
  var fldrNamesRng  = theSheet.getRange(4,1,theSheet.getLastRow()-3,1);
  Logger.log('fldrNamesRng: ' + fldrNamesRng);
  
  var folderNames  = fldrNamesRng.getValues();
  Logger.log('folderNames: ' + folderNames);
  
  var oneD_FolderNames = folderNames.join().split(",");
  Logger.log('oneD_FolderNames: ' + oneD_FolderNames);
  
  makeTheFolders(oneD_FolderNames);
  putFilesIntoFolders(oneD_FolderNames);
};

function makeTheFolders(theFolderNames,cell) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();
  
  var i=0,
      folderObj;
  
  for (i=0;i<theFolderNames.length;i+=1) {
    folderObj = DriveApp.createFolder(theFolderNames[i] + " " + cell);
    
    folderIds.push(folderObj.getId())
  };
};

function putFilesIntoFolders(arrayOfFolderNames,theFolderNames,cell) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("File to Copy");
  var dest_folder  = "";
  
  var baseFileName = "",
      newfile,
      newFileName = "",
      i=0,
      j=0;

  for (i=0;i<arrayOfFolderNames.length;i+=1) {
    var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder that has File to be Copied");
    dest_folder  = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i]);
    Logger.log('dest_folder' + dest_folder);

    baseFileName = arrayOfFolderNames[i];
    
    for (j=1; j<16; j+=1) {
      var newFileName = baseFileName + " " + cell + " " + j.toString();
      var fileCopy = file.makeCopy(); 
      
/* Code I tried */
//      var copyID = fileCopy.getId();
//      var copySs = DriveApp.getFileById(copyID);
//      var copySheet = copySs.getSheets()[0];
//      var copyCell = copySheet.getRange(1,9,1,1);
//      copyCell.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Question Details!C' + j + 3 + ':AX' + j + 3 + ')');
     
      var namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName("_" + newFileName);
     
      if (j<10) {
          dest_folder.addFile(namedFileCopy);
          source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy); 
      }  else {
         var namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName(newFileName); 
          dest_folder.addFile(namedFileCopy);
          source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy);
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, you just need to make sure you open the new (copied) spreadsheet as a Spreadsheet object so that you can use Spreadsheet methods on it.

Instead of:

```
  var copySs = DriveApp.getFileById(copyID);
```

Use:

```
  var copySs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyID);
```

By doing so, `copySs` will be a variable that represents a [Spreadsheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), and the other lines you already wrote will actually make sense!

```
  var copySheet = copySs.getSheets()[0];
  var copyCell = copySheet.getRange(1,9,1,1);
  copyCell.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Question Details!C' + j + 3 + ':AX' + j + 3 + ')');
```